# Where can I find streams of German comedies that include subtitles and are in Hochdeutsch?

Tags: resource, standard-german

What are the best sites where I can find German comedy shows with German subtitles? I'm learning German and am quite enthusiastic about it (more than any of my other subjects). I've enjoyed watching what there is to offer on YouTube and I have found Austrian comedies quite hard to understand.

Comment: Both german public broadcasters (ARD and ZDF) maintain their programmes in a so-called *Mediathek* for internet broadcast. Some of their self-produced programmes are subbed in German for deaf viewers. Check http://ardmediathek/tv and http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek . Subbed programs are typically marked with "UT" (Untertitel)

Comment: But note that comedy shows are rarely really Standard German - regional dialects are not uncommon in this genre.

Comment: There are German comedies?

Comment: @CarstenS That was not funny.

Comment: @Hulk: Extra3 ist Standarddeutsch, die Heute-Show, Pussy-Dings, vom WDR, Mitternachtsspitzen ebd., Ladies Night, Krömer Show, dieses Imbis-Dings-mit-Bademantel, Nuhr auf Hochdeutsch, Böhmermann. Das waren die, die mir spontan im ÖR einfallen. Im privaten kuck ich kaum, aber manchmal begegne ich da auch Comedy, XY-Najar-Show, gibt es sowas? Dann Anke Engelke, Titel entfallen. Dieser Stadionfüller, das ist leicht berlinerisch gefärbt, aber auch nicht Mundart. Rar ist eher Dialekt. Im bay. Fernsehen gibt es was (nicht Schlachthof, der gehört oben hin), im SWR gibt es arg pfälzisches.

Comment: You can also find some productions of the Austrian state television on their Mediathek: http://tvthek.orf.at/

Comment: @userunknown: Um das durch Wissen aus den Privaten zu ergänzen: Anke Engelke macht (u.a.?) *Ladykracher*, vergleichbare "Sketch-Sammlungen" wären z.B. *Knallerfrauen* und *Sechserpack*. Daneben gibt es aber auch einige deutsche Comedy-Serien, die eine durchgehende Geschichte erzählen, wie beispielsweise *Das Amt*, *Anke* (war das der Titel?) und *Pastewka*.

Comment: @tofro: One issue to consider is whether such services are accessible from abroad - the OP didn't specify, but it is a reasonable assumption that learners of German might notbbe located in Germany. I haven't had much luck in the past trying to watch shows on the websites of German tv channels from abroad, there usually seemed to be some sort of geoblocking for licensing reasons.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Both sites are perfectly accessible from Sweden and work from there - I obviously can't know for all countries, though.

Comment: @tofro: That's great to know. Maybe it is only an issue with the private channels.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the [German Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/browse) offers many German comedians like Dieter Nuhr, Kaya Yanar, Hape Kerkeling and so on, where you can enable German subtitles.

Take a look at the genre [German Comedies](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/63115) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start would be probaly the pages of [ARD](http://www.ardmediathek.de/tv) and [ZDF](http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek/hauptnavigation/startseite?flash=off) as well as [3sat](http://www.3sat.de/mediathek/) which also brings some Austrian and Swiss stuff. But most titles are only accessible from within Germany (Geo blocking, copyright laws) and also most of this kind of stuff isn’t subtitled.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention [ARTE](http://www.arte.tv/guide/en/ "Medithek of german/france coopation broadcaster"), most of their stuff is subtitled, but I don't know is the have comedies in their selection.

Comment: If you forgot something, you can [edit] your post ;)

Comment: Yeah I know, but I feel the post isn't finished yet so I wrote it as comment first before inegrating it in the answer, is that not the way it is suppossed to work work, isn't it?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do, of course. Some people edit their posts a number of times (if it happens within five minutes, it won’t generate an entry in the post’s history). Others collect and edit in bulk later. I was merely reminding you as you are a rather new user and I cannot know how well you know SE. On that note: You can take a [tour] of the site ;)

Comment: Ach ich schau hier grade nebenbei rein, wärend ich auf eine Antwort auf eine frage auf einer anderen SE Seite warte, bis jetzt konnte mir noch keiner helfen, aber das wir zu off topic jetzt.